# json dump to a file

Tags: python, json

Hi have a json file as below -

```
{
    "Account": {
        "name": "demo_account_1",
        "Containers": [
            {
                "name": "abcd",
                "created_at": "1189090948.18945",
            },
            {
                "name": "pqrs",
                "created_at": "1234558.18945",
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now I want to populate this file this python script so that I can add more entries to Account or Containers. i.e after insertion of a container the file will look like -

```
{
    "Account": {
        "name": "demo_account_1",
        "Containers": [
            {
                "name": "abcd",
                "created_at": "1189090948.18945",
            },
            {
                "name": "pqrs",
                "created_at": "1234558.18945",
            },
            {
                "name": "mnop",
                "created_at": "100000.12345",
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: More specifically, there are three parts of this problem: Reading a JSON file, appending an item to a list, and writing a JSON file. Which of the three is/are unclear to you?

Comment: part 2 and part 3. specially part 3

Comment: [There's a module for that.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) Read the docs; you want the `load` and `dump` functions.

Comment: I read that but I am unable to dump data exactly in the required cell

Comment: Please give an example of it, I am new to json.

Comment: Please someone help me on this

Answer (score 7):

The file you have is not valid JSON (there is a closing brace missing, and a few commas too many.

But if you have a valid file like

```
{
    "Account": {
        "name": "demo_account_1",
        "Containers": [
            {
                "name": "abcd",
                "created_at": "1189090948.18945"
            },
            {
                "name": "pqrs",
                "created_at": "1234558.18945"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

then this snippet will do what you want:

```
import json
with open("test.json") as infile:
    j = json.load(infile)

j["Account"]["Containers"].append({"name": "mnop", "created_at": "100000.12345"})

with open("test.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(j, outfile, indent=4)
```